# Problem with docker daemon after installing (and unnistaling) docker desktop

Tags: services, docker

I tried to install, docker desktop on my pc and after getting it, a project I had stopped working because of it I guess and docker. After supposedly uninstalling it with the following commands:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i docker

sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-compose-plugin
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-compose-plugin

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo groupdel docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
```

I tried again to install it with sudo apt-get install docker.io, I got a dependency issue with containerd and runc. I was able to "supposedly" install again with the commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove containerd.io
sudo apt install docker.io docker-compose -y
```

But now I can't start a simple container because I get the following error no matter what I do:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/mnemonic/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The docker daemon is indeed running, if I check it with systemctl status. I have checked the docker privileges with:

```
ls -l /home/mnemonic/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
```

And they are correct. I have created the docker user group and joined it. I have restarted and started the docker service dozens of times, just like my pc. I have manually started the docker daemon, to no avail.

Please I hope someone can help me, at this point I don't know what else to do I have been having this problem for days and honestly I don't want to format my whole pc because of a problem like this.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found the solution. Apparently there is a json docker config file in ubuntu and other debian based distros that set docker "context" to "docker-desktop".

I have just deleted this 2 lines in `$HOME/.docker/config.json`:

```
credsStore
currentContext
```

The last one, "currentContext", was set to "docker-desktop", which was unninstalled.

Source for this solution was found here:

https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/20

where you can found a user comment that redirects you to:

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/uninstall/

I love them.